# Возможно ли использовать в веб-приложении обычные сокеты (не WebSockets)?

Tags: веб-программирование, сокеты

Сервер для видеотрансляций должен работать как с клиентами на C++ по обычным сокетам, так и с запросами из браузера. Смотрел в сторону веб-сокетов - оказались слишком замороченные. Найденные в сети функции кодирования/декодирования сообщений websocket то нормально обработают присланные из браузера данные, то выдадут какую-то мешанину. Нет стабильности.

Нужно иметь возможность просматривать в браузере до 20 веб-камер одновременно, на одной странице, или камеру + экран. Кадры передаются от клиентов на C++ в формате jpeg. Также между клиентом и наблюдателем передаётся дополнительная информация - например, id и имя пользователя, доступна ли камера для трансляции, перевёрнуто ли изображение с камеры, транслировать ли данному клиенту вообще или нет.

**ВОПРОС:**

Есть ли возможность использовать в веб-приложении обычные сокеты? Любым способом - flash, модули какие-нибудь на pyton или чём угодно, лишь бы обеспечить быстрый обмен данными без дополнительных заголовков и формальностей.

Comment: Видео можно передавать картинкой в формате MJPEG...

Comment: Да можно использовать любые сокеты из любой библиотеки которую получится подключить.

Comment: @nick_n_a из браузера? Ну-ну.

Comment: Недочитал слово браузер...

Comment: Да, проблема именно в браузере. Текущая система работает по HTTP. Image.onload=<url_следующего кадра> и тому подобное. Работает, но апач под нагрузкой "задыхается" и фпс падает до 2-10 кадров

Comment: «Найденные в сети функции кодирования/декодирования» — а почему функции, а не полноценные библиотеки? Багрепорты их авторам отправляли?

Comment: Может посмотреть в сторону flash (as3)? Он поддерживает потоковое видео. (html5 вроде тоже но всётаки)

Comment: Тут вопрос не столько в самой передаче видео, а в реализации стабильного асинхронного сетевого взаимодействия. Ведь кроме видео передаются ещё данные для управления потоками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Нет, нельзя*.

*) Можно использовать такие технологии, как ActiveX, Flash, Java-апплеты, Sliverlight, Unity. Там всюду есть сокеты.

Но ни одну из них нельзя назвать кроссплатформенной. Так, ActiveX работает только в IE. Flash не работает на андроидах. А остальные используют древний NPAPI (Netscape Plugin API), от поддержки которого отказались разработчики Google Chrome.

Общая тенденция такова, что возможные варианты исполнения произвольного кода в браузере последовательно закрываются в пользу ограниченного стека разрешенных технологий.

Кроме того, разобраться с веб-сокетами будет попросту проще, чем осваивать сразу несколько технологий из списка выше для закрытия всех платформ.

---

PS но если вы и правда собираетесь работать с потоковым видео - надо брать нормальные системы для работы с ним, поддерживающие передачу по RTP. При передаче видео по TCP невозможно добиться отсутствия лагов и рывков под нагрузкой!

надо брать готовый WebRTC-клиент, готовый WebRTC-сервер и не велосипедить.

Вот полезная статья на эту тему:

[Транслируем видеопоток с IP-камеры с помощью WebRTC](https://habrahabr.ru/post/229243/)

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Хочу уточнить - возможно на одной странице создать несколько веб-сокетов на один адрес:порт и получать разные данные (которые предназначаются для инициировавшего обмен сокета). Просто у меня несколько сокетов пытаются работать, а ответы все в один котёл идут - должны загружаться разные изображения в разные теги img, а я вижу только один img, где "воюют" между собой разные кадры

Comment: На клиентской стороне вы получаете те данные, которые передали на сервере, и наоборот. Если там воюют разные кадры - значит, на сервере что-то напутано.

Comment: @Iceman на всякий случай еще можно по разным путям подключаться

Comment: по разным путям? Что Вы имеете ввиду? На оборудовании открыт один порт, который проброшен на нужный порт виртуальной машины. У всей этой затеи есть только 80 для апача, и другой для видеосервиса. Больше портов никто не даст.

Comment: @Iceman конечная точка веб-сокета задается не парой адрес-порт, а своим URL.

Comment: То есть, каждому веб-сокету на странице давать url типа /ws/1:port, /ws/2:port ... а из корня /ws просто запускается сам сервер который этот порт будет слушать? Так?

Comment: @Iceman у вас формат URL какой-то странный... Но да, если сервер не обращает внимание на часть URL, то на клиенте ее можно менять как угодно.

Comment: Ну сейчас он такой `new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8081");`. Какие разные пути тут указывать то?

Comment: @Iceman `new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8081/hello-world/1?foo=bar");`

Comment: Ну да, работает. Спасибо за наводку. И ещё раз благодарю за ответ.